# python subprocess running unoconv throwing CalledProcessError exit code 8

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run [unoconv](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/) to convert a set of documents in a folder like so:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_call(['unoconv', "/home/foo/ve/pdf/pdf/pdf_media/" + <filename parameter>)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print "conversion error: ", e
```

Now, I run the above code within a django view - and it runs as expects all the time i.e converts the document to PDF, but, sometimes, the above code throws me the following exception:

```
Command '['unoconv',  u'/home/foo/ve/pdf/pdf/pdf_media/WgYozM7.doc']' returned non-zero exit status -8
```

However, when I go to the folder, I see that the conversion has happened and the PDF generated as expected.

I fail to understand what this exit code means (I searched the docs of unoconv but couldnt find any exit code 8).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your subprocess has a negative exit-code. This is not an application code, but caused by the OS terminating your program. The negative number is the signal-number the process received. On my mac, -8 stands for SIGFPE.

Comment: I am on a linux box (debian wheezy).. I am trying to find out what -8 means for this i.e negative exit status in linux - but I am not able to find any info. Any ideas?